# I want to unwrap faces automaticaly and export to autocad

Tags: modeling, uv, export

I need to export the blender file to AutoCAD or any other program that I can use to work with the laser cut machine

Comment: Blender can export in several file formats but without knowing what formats AutoCAD accepts or any information about what you're trying to export it's impossible to help you. We can only help with problems using Blender so advice about external programs are off-topic here. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask